# How to remove parameters in a url string

Tags: php, string, url

I have a string that looks like this, like a URL that has parameters.

```
folder/tested/file.js?p1=v1&p2=v2
```

How can I manipulate this string so as to remove all params, so that it ends up looking like this

```
folder/tested/file.js
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out parse_url() - http://php.net/function.parse-url

`$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);`

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = explode("?", "folder/tested/file.js?p1=v1&p2=v2");
$array[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the `explode` workaround in this case:

```
$path = strtok($url, "?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method that is somewhat 'dirty':

```
$tmp = 'folder/tested/file.js?p1=v1&p2=v2';
$pos = strpos($tmp, '?');
$url = substr($tmp, 0, $pos);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try splitting by a '/' then by a '?' into two parts, and just taking what you need from both operations:

http://php.net/function.explode